# Qual a diferença entre window.location e window.location.href?

Tags: javascript, redirecionamento

Sempre usei `window.location.href` para redirecionar a outra página interna ou URL externa, mas ao usar apenas `window.location` (sem o `.href`) produz o mesmo resultado, ou seja, faz o mesmo redirecionamento.

### Exemplo com `window.location`:

```js
function redir(){
   window.location = "./";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="redir()">Ir</button>
```

### Exemplo com `window.location.href`:

```js
function redir(){
   window.location.href = "./";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="redir()">Ir</button>
```

Com isso me suscitou a dúvida: qual a diferença entre as duas instruções e quando usar uma ou outra?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- window.location = É referente ao objeto location de window, você pode usá-la quando necessitar de usar o objeto por inteiro, ou mais de uma propriedade do mesmo.
- window.location.href = É especificamente ao atributo href de location. (String)

Answer (score 18):

`window.location` é um objeto que contém todas as informações sobre o local atual do documento (*host*, *href*, *port*, *protocol*, etc.), ou seja, é um objeto completo e pode usar para operar de várias formas com cada informação individual. [Documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

`window.location.href` é apenas uma *string* com o URL completo do site atual quando tudo o que precisa é só a representação textual do URL.

Eles agem da mesma forma quando você atribui um URL a eles - eles redirecionam para a página que você atribui, mas você pode ver diferenças entre eles quando abre o console do navegador (Firebug ou Developer Tools) e escreve `window.location` e `window.location.href`. [Documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/href).

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9903720/221800).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).